# nRF24L01+ (RF24) radio with Arduino Micro

Tags: rf, arduino-pro-micro

I purchased several nRF24L01+ (RF24) radios to use with my Arduino Uno and Micro.

Using the [GettingStarted](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/GettingStarted_8pde-example.html) sketch and nRF24L01+ connected to my Uno, I get nice debugging info in my serial monitor. However when I connect the nRF24L01+ to my Micro, upload the sketch and open the serial monitor I get no debugging information. There is no info displayed in the serial monitor.

Also the Arduino Uno when set to Transmit, does not see the other nRF24L01+. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my pinout to connect the nRF24L01+ to the Micro:

```
Line    From Arduino Pin    To nRF24L01+ 
GND     GND                 1
3V3     3V3                 2
CE      9                   3
CSN     10                  4
SCK     SCK                 5
MOSI    MOSI                6
MISO    MISO                7
```

Here the nRF24L01+

[image: Nrf24L01+]

Sketch

```
/*
 Copyright (C) 2011 J. Coliz <maniacbug@ymail.com>

 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 version 2 as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "printf.h"

//
// Hardware configuration
//

// Set up nRF24L01 radio on SPI bus plus pins 9 & 10 

RF24 radio(9,10);

//
// Topology
//

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
const uint64_t pipes[2] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };

//
// Role management
//
// Set up role.  This sketch uses the same software for all the nodes
// in this system.  Doing so greatly simplifies testing.  
//

// The various roles supported by this sketch
typedef enum { role_ping_out = 1, role_pong_back } role_e;

// The debug-friendly names of those roles
const char* role_friendly_name[] = { "invalid", "Ping out", "Pong back"};

// The role of the current running sketch
role_e role = role_pong_back;

void setup(void)
{
  //
  // Print preamble
  //

  Serial.begin(57600);
  printf_begin();
  printf("\n\rRF24/examples/GettingStarted/\n\r");
  printf("ROLE: %s\n\r",role_friendly_name[role]);
  printf("*** PRESS 'T' to begin transmitting to the other node\n\r");

  //
  // Setup and configure rf radio
  //

  radio.begin();

  // optionally, increase the delay between retries & # of retries
  radio.setRetries(15,15);

  // optionally, reduce the payload size.  seems to
  // improve reliability
  radio.setPayloadSize(8);

  //
  // Open pipes to other nodes for communication
  //

  // This simple sketch opens two pipes for these two nodes to communicate
  // back and forth.
  // Open 'our' pipe for writing
  // Open the 'other' pipe for reading, in position #1 (we can have up to 5 pipes open for reading)

  if ( role == role_ping_out )
  {
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
  }

  //
  // Start listening
  //

  radio.startListening();

  //
  // Dump the configuration of the rf unit for debugging
  //

  radio.printDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{
  //
  // Ping out role.  Repeatedly send the current time
  //

  if (role == role_ping_out)
  {
    // First, stop listening so we can talk.
    radio.stopListening();

    // Take the time, and send it.  This will block until complete
    unsigned long time = millis();
    printf("Now sending %lu...",time);
    bool ok = radio.write( &time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

    if (ok)
      printf("ok...");
    else
      printf("failed.\n\r");

    // Now, continue listening
    radio.startListening();

    // Wait here until we get a response, or timeout (250ms)
    unsigned long started_waiting_at = millis();
    bool timeout = false;
    while ( ! radio.available() && ! timeout )
      if (millis() - started_waiting_at > 200 )
        timeout = true;

    // Describe the results
    if ( timeout )
    {
      printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
    }
    else
    {
      // Grab the response, compare, and send to debugging spew
      unsigned long got_time;
      radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

      // Spew it
      printf("Got response %lu, round-trip delay: %lu\n\r",got_time,millis()-got_time);
    }

    // Try again 1s later
    delay(1000);
  }

  //
  // Pong back role.  Receive each packet, dump it out, and send it back
  //

  if ( role == role_pong_back )
  {
    // if there is data ready
    if ( radio.available() )
    {
      // Dump the payloads until we've gotten everything
      unsigned long got_time;
      bool done = false;
      while (!done)
      {
        // Fetch the payload, and see if this was the last one.
        done = radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );

        // Spew it
        printf("Got payload %lu...",got_time);

        // Delay just a little bit to let the other unit
        // make the transition to receiver
        delay(20);
      }

      // First, stop listening so we can talk
      radio.stopListening();

      // Send the final one back.
      radio.write( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
      printf("Sent response.\n\r");

      // Now, resume listening so we catch the next packets.
      radio.startListening();
    }
  }

  //
  // Change roles
  //

  if ( Serial.available() )
  {
    char c = toupper(Serial.read());
    if ( c == 'T' && role == role_pong_back )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO TRANSMIT ROLE -- PRESS 'R' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      // Become the primary transmitter (ping out)
      role = role_ping_out;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[1]);
    }
    else if ( c == 'R' && role == role_ping_out )
    {
      printf("*** CHANGING TO RECEIVE ROLE -- PRESS 'T' TO SWITCH BACK\n\r");

      // Become the primary receiver (pong back)
      role = role_pong_back;
      radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
      radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my 2ct are you use the wrong pins. This is really odd [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro). You have the Atmega Pins, the consecutive pins on the header and the pins written on the PCB, i.e. 9 could be 9 on the PCB which is A9. I have a chnese 'Micro Pro' and I switched to (2,3) instead of (9,10).

Comment: I assume you do see the first few `printf`s in the serial console, as they are called even before the RF24 is initialized.

Comment: Changing the pins to 2 and 3 and setting them with `RF24 radio(2,3);`, works. However the info to be displayed when `setup()` is run never displays. Even though this does not display the 2 radios are talking to each other. The other weird thing I noticed is that when connected to the Micro, the radio drops. I don't seem to have this issue with the `Uno` or when I have it connected to a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @bersch - Make it an answer and its yours. I was able to fix the issue with the radio drops by testing with my Mac and not an old PC. Not sure if that was this issue, but I am not having issues now

Comment: This [link](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo) could be of interest. The 'power problems' section confirms power issues at 3V3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you use the wrong pins. This is really a pitfall [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro).

You have the Atmega Pins, the consecutive pins of the headers and the pins written on the PCB, i.e. 9 could be 9 on the PCB which is A9.

I have a Chinese 'Micro Pro' and I switched to (2,3) instead of (9,10).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `9` means `D9` and not `A9`.

Everytime Arduino projects assign a pin with no prefix, it is denoted as data I/O and if the Analog pins are used then it would say `A9`.

The nRF24L01 handles data I/O and not analog input.

Comment: Some good, but not necessarily obvious, points made...